# For xml error because column name has spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have the following table (called temp1):

```
+-------+------+------+------+----------------------+
| cntry | col1 | col2 | col3 | ACV Distribution (w) |
+-------+------+------+------+----------------------+
| UK    |  100 |  100 |  100 |                    0 |
| FR    |  100 |  100 |  100 |                    0 |
+-------+------+------+------+----------------------+
```

When running this statement:

```
DECLARE @listStr varchar(MAX);
DECLARE @query varchar(MAX);
drop table if exists temp2 ;
set @liststr = (  select * from temp1  where cntry = 'UK' for xml path('') )
set @query =('SELECT top 10 col1,col2,col3,' + @listStr + ' INTO temp2 FROM temp3' )
execute(@query); 
SELECT * FROM temp2 ;
```

I get this error:

> ERROR: Column name ACV Distribution (w) contains an invalid XML identifier as required by FOR XML

I am stuck here as I can not change name of cols and have to use dynamic sql.

Comment: Use `quotename()`.

Comment: can I use quotename for * because as per definition i have put the string and quote_character

Comment: You need to chane the column name so that it becomes a valid SQL elelemnt name... like `SELECT ..., [ACV Distribution (w)] AS ACV_Distribution_w`

Comment: @SalmanA can't change the col name , in my case they are standard

Comment: You cannot have XML like `<ACV Distribution (w)>10</ACV Distribution (w)>`. Please describe the problem that you're trying to solve instead of the error you want to suppress.

Comment: that's why I need solution for this or any alternative method where i can select cols dynamically without changing names

Comment: what is temp3 here? Without using your current approach, can you explain what is the actual requirement? Maybe there could be other approaches to solve...

Comment: What does PRINT @query give you